# How to show Get-Help in powershell when no parameters are given

Tags: powershell

Ok, I tried to look around and figure out how to do this, but wasn't able to figure it out. Here's what I want to do.

```
# Run script normally
.\myscript.ps1 "blah" "yo"
```

These should do the same thing

```
Get-Help .\myscript.ps1
.\myscript.ps1
```

I want to be able to use the Get-Help syntax, but don't want to have to repeat it somewhere with a parameter switch statement. If this has been answered somewhere else, feel free to point me there.

Comment: I'm not sure that's a good idea - it goes against how every other PowerShell command works and will probably annoy the users.

Comment: Advanced functions have parameter based help. If the user does something wrong Powershell will request what is missing. No need to display _all_ the help. Just like if you type `Get-ChildItem` and nothing more

Comment: Well, this is a small script that is going to be used by people who have never used Powershell before. So, while it will be different from how other Powershell commands work, they likely won't even use those other commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following code to the top of your script:

```
if($args.Count -eq 0) {
    Get-Help $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    return
}
```

Comment: this only works if you don't have required parameters

Answer (score 2):

$PSBoundParameters.Values.Count will give you the count of parameters passed when you use param() in your script. You can then use $args to find anything else entered that is outside these parameters. So if you test for both when using param you can get help response.

Example parametertest.ps1

```
param([string]$val1,$val2,[switch]$val3)
if ( $PSBoundParameters.Values.Count -eq 0 -and $args.count -eq 0 ) {
    Get-Help $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
    return 
    }
if ( $PSBoundParameters.Values.Count -eq 0 ){ 
    Write-Output ("No parameters passed")     
    return
    }
else {     write-output("val1=$val1 val2=$val2 val3=$val3") }
if ( $args -and $args.count -gt 0 ) {
    Write-Output ("Found Args $args")  }
if ( $PSBoundParameters.Values.Count -eq 0 -and  $args -and $args.count -eq 0
```

Example output

powershell -File parametertest.ps1

> parametertest.ps1 [[-val1] < string>] [[-val2] < Object>] [-val3]

powershell -File parametertest.ps1 sometest 123

> val1=sometest val2=123 val3=False

powershell -File parametertest.ps1 -val1 stuff -val2 123 -val3

> val1=stuff val2=123 val3=True

powershell -File parametertest.ps1 -unknown parameter

> No parameters passed
>
> Found Args -unknown parameter